# Using PWM on raspberry pi 3 vs pi 2 with bcm2835 library

Tags: pi-3, pwm

In one application we are using the raspberry p to control motor speed via PWM. We were able to get a valid working code on the raspberry pi 2, but when we transferred this code and drivers over to the pi 3 the code simply does not work. Is there any easy thing we are missing in switching from the pi 2 to the pi 3 to get this code working?

```c
#include <bcm2835.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define PIN RPI_BPLUS_GPIO_J8_32
#define PIN2 RPI_BPLUS_GPIO_J8_33
#define CTL_PIN RPI_BPLUS_GPIO_J8_29
#define CTL_PIN2 RPI_BPLUS_GPIO_J8_31

#define PWM_CHANNEL 0
#define PWM_CHANNEL2 1

#define RANGE 1024

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
//      bcm2835_delay(10000);
    if (!bcm2835_init())
     return 1;

    // Set the output pin to Alt Fun 5, to allow PWM channel 0 to be output    there
    bcm2835_gpio_fsel(PIN, BCM2835_GPIO_FSEL_ALT0);
    bcm2835_gpio_fsel(PIN2, BCM2835_GPIO_FSEL_ALT0);
    bcm2835_gpio_fsel(CTL_PIN, BCM2835_GPIO_FSEL_OUTP);
    bcm2835_gpio_fsel(CTL_PIN2, BCM2835_GPIO_FSEL_OUTP);

    // Clock divider is set to 16.
    // With a divider of 16 and a RANGE of 1024, in MARKSPACE mode,
    // the pulse repetition frequency will be
    // 1.2MHz/1024 = 1171.875Hz, suitable for driving a DC motor with PWM
    bcm2835_pwm_set_clock(BCM2835_PWM_CLOCK_DIVIDER_16);
    bcm2835_pwm_set_mode(PWM_CHANNEL, 1, 1);
    bcm2835_pwm_set_range(PWM_CHANNEL, RANGE);
    bcm2835_pwm_set_mode(PWM_CHANNEL2, 1, 1);
    bcm2835_pwm_set_range(PWM_CHANNEL2, RANGE);

    // Vary the PWM m/s ratio between 1/RANGE and (RANGE-1)/RANGE
    int direction = 1;
    int data = 1;
    int j;
    bcm2835_gpio_write(CTL_PIN, HIGH);
    bcm2835_gpio_write(CTL_PIN2, HIGH);

    for (j=0;j<4096;j++)
      {
        if (j==2048) {
          bcm2835_gpio_write(CTL_PIN, LOW);
//        bcm2835_gpio_write(CTL_PIN2, LOW);
        }
    if (data == 1)
      direction = 1;
    else if (data == RANGE-1)
      direction = -1;
    data += direction;
      bcm2835_pwm_set_data(PWM_CHANNEL, data);
      bcm2835_pwm_set_data(PWM_CHANNEL2, data);
    bcm2835_delay(10);
      }
      bcm2835_pwm_set_data(PWM_CHANNEL, 0);
      bcm2835_pwm_set_data(PWM_CHANNEL2, 0);

    bcm2835_close();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Would you be able to elaborate on 'simply does not work'? Does it run? Does it run badly? Does it throw exceptions? Are there bad fires?

Comment: There is some [discussion on the libbcm2835 mail list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/bcm2835/Pi$203|sort:relevance/bcm2835/rencLf-Rl2o/VsDPjxXrBQAJ) regarding the Pi 3 where it apparently works for basic purposes (toggling a GPIO) but does not refer to PWM.   In that thread the author mentions "adding some notes to the documentation" about the Pi 3 in "the next release" but AFAICT the current release (1.50) predates that discussion.  You should probably get on the mail list and ask about this.

Comment: @goobering sure, in our test code the motors spin in one direction speeding up then down, then do the same in the reverse direction. This works on the pi2. When run on the pi 3 there is simply no motion in the motors. It compiles fine and now errors are thrown when running.

Comment: This problem seems to be limited to the bcm2835 library.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the relevant thread for this problem- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/bcm2835/pwm$20not$20working%7Csort:relevance/bcm2835/mZjLtVmlKV8/d1BheSSKAgAJ

According to the discussion, you'd need to have sudo/root permissions while running the C executable for the PWM to work.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem just now! At the end I discovered that the GPIO18 works properly while GPIO12 does not work (there is no PWM signal).

Just change:

```
#define PIN RPI_GPIO_P1_12
```

by

```
#define PIN RPI_GPIO_P1_18
```

Thats all.